# Magento 2 Associate Develeper Certification Question

Tags: magento2

**Q:- `\Magento\Sales\Model\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::getList` accepts a
`SearchCriteriaInterface` to filter and sort information.**

**What class assists in creating an instance for** `SearchCriteriaInterface`**?**

**A**. `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaFactory`

**B**. `\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder`

**C**. `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\SearchCriteria`

**D**. `\Magento\Backend\Api\SearchCriteriaGenerator`

CAN SOMEONE PLEASE EXPLAIN THIS TO ME AND WHAT IS THE CORRECT ANS FOR THIS QUESTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct ans is -
**B. \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder**

A Builder is similar to a factory in Magento2, it will help to instantiate a class.